# Laravel relationship with nested columns?

Tags: mongodb, laravel

I am using Laravel with mongodb, i have little understanding in laravel eloquent relationship,currently my collection structure is as follows

```
collection name:general_details

{
    "id": 01,
    "personal_details":[
        [
            "emp_id":10,
            "blood_group":"B+ve"
        ],
        [
            "emp_id":11,
            "blood_group":"B+ve"
        ]
    ]
}

collection name:employee_details

{
    "emp_id":10,
    "emp_name":"Alex"
},
{
    "emp_id":11,
    "emp_name":"Ramesh"
}
```

i want to create eloquent relationship between two collections for "emp_id", please suggest any solution?

Comment: What your model name for both table?

Comment: Model names for both, GenDetails, EmpDetails

Answer (score 0):

**In GenDetails model**

```
public function empdetails(){
 return $this->hasOne('App\EmpDetails');
}
```

**In EmpDetails Model**

```
public function genDetails(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\GenDetails');
}
```

here is one to one relationship between GenDetails and EmpDetails model. So learn more from [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) for Eloquent Relationship.

Comment: No, my collection have nested columns, thats the problem

Answer (score 0):

In **GenDetail Model** put this relationship

```
public function empDetails(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\EmpDetails','emp_id','personal_details.emp_id');
}
```

i think this relationship will defiantly work for you.